# AndroidでListViewを使うがArrayAdapterの第2引数のtextViewResourceIdの存在

Tags: android

AndroidでListViewを使う際にArrayAdapterを使いますが、この第2引数のtextViewResourceIdは何を示しているのでしょうか？下記のソースの場合、android.R.layout配下のリソースファイルにsimple_expandable_list_item_1というものを書き出すことなのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

```
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     String[] members = { "mhidaka", "rongon_xp", "kacchi0516", "kobashinG",
                "seit", "kei_i_t", "furusin_oriver" };

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, members);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

第2引数は`textViewResourceId`ではなく`resource`ですね。

`android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1`というシステム組み込みのレイアウトリソースを利用する、ということです。

`textViewResourceId`を使うケースは、レイアウトリソースのうちどの`TextView`を利用するのかを記述する必要がある場合です。質問にあるような、`textViewResourceId`を指定しないコンストラクタにおいては、`android.R.text1`がIDの`TextView`を`findViewById()`で取得して、そこへ表示します。

---

**参考**

- [ArrayAdapter - AndroidDeveloper](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)